# Todo App in React- Wanted to add Search bar for the app

Tags: reactjs

I have added the search feature in my app but there is a problem. I am able to search all through the todo list but when I remove the text from the search input  the todo list did not change according to that.
I am able to search through the items but when I delete one character from the search input the todo list did not change according to that. Help me. Thanks in advance.

**App Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PrintTodo from "./printtodo"
import Addtodo from "./addTodo"


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    todos: [
        {id:1, content:"Buy Tomatoes"},
    ]
  }

  deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
      return todo.id !== id
    })

    this.setState({
      todos
    })
  }

  addTodo = (todo) => {
    todo.id = Math.random()
    // console.log(todo)
    let todos = [...this.state.todos, todo]
    this.setState({
      todos
    })
  }

  button = () => {
    this.setState({
      todos: []
    })
    }

    form = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    search = (e) => {
       const value = e.target.value;
       const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
         return todo.content.toLowerCase().includes(value);
       })
      console.log(value)
       this.setState({
        todos
       })
    }


  render(){

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">

          <header className="text-center text-light my-4">
            <h1>ToDo - List</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.form}>
              <input type="text" name="search" value={this.state.content} onChange={this.search} placeholder="Search ToDo's" className="form-control m-auto"/>
            </form>
          </header>


        <PrintTodo addTodo={this.state.todos} deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}/>


        <Addtodo addTodo={this.addTodo} allTodos={this.button}/>


        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Printtodo Component**

```
import React from 'react'

const printTodo = ({addTodo, deleteTodo, }) => {
    // console.log(addTodo)
    const todoList = addTodo.length ? (
        addTodo.map(todo => {
            return (
                <ul className="list-group todos mx-auto text-light" key={todo.id}>
                    <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <span>{todo.content}</span>
                        <i className="far fa-trash-alt delete" onClick={()=>{deleteTodo(todo.id)}}></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            )
        })
    ) : (
        <p className="text-center text-light">You don't have any ToDo's</p>
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {todoList}
      </div>
    )

    } 

export default printTodo
```

**Addtodo Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Addtodo extends Component{
    state = {
        content: ""
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            content: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.addTodo(this.state)
        this.setState({
            content: ""
        })
    }



    render(){
        // console.log(this.props.allTodos)
        return(
            <div>
                <form className="text-center my-4 add text-light" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="add">Add a New ToDo</label>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="add" id="add" className="form-control m-auto" value={this.state.content}/>
                </form>

                <button onClick={() => {this.props.allTodos()}}>Clear Whole List</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Addtodo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search = (e) => {
   const value = e.target.value;
   const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
     return todo.content.toLowerCase().includes(value);
   })
  console.log(value)
   this.setState({
    todos
   })
}
```

If you also log todos you may see todos does not change after you delete characters - because you have set the filtered todos in the new state so the original todo list state which holds more results is gone.

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you can run your filter somewhere else which does not affect your todo list state. For example, in your printtodo component, something like this:

```
const printTodo = ({addTodo, deleteTodo, searchText }) => {
  const todoList = addTodo.filter(todo => {
         return todo.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
       }).map(todo => ......);
  // ...


  }
```